# getting various information in linux terminal

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

Does anyone know how to get these information in linux using terminal?

- The location of the end of the code (text) segment of the process (hexadecimal).
- The address of a function inside the code segment (hexadecimal). This is just the address of
  one of your functions.
- The address of a string literal (hexadecimal).
- The location of the end of the initialized data segment of the process (hexadecimal).
- The address of a variable in the initialized data area (hexadecimal).
- The location of the end of the uninitialized data segment (BSS) of the process
  (hexadecimal).
- The address of a variable in the uninitialized data area (hexadecimal).
- The location of the end of the heap of the process, also known as the program break
  (hexadecimal).
- The address of a local variable on the stack (hexadecimal).
- The base address of the command line arguments “argv” (hexadecimal).
- The base address of the environment variables “envp” (hexadecimal).
- The address of the zero terminating the last environment variable string (hexadecimal).

Comment: Is this homework?  What have you tried?

Comment: yes.. i just could not find any commands that gets base address of anystuff.. giving me any instruction for how to do will really help me out... so i can get an idea how to do it haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest

```
man -S5 proc
```

see e.g. http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc